# Is there any better way doing this query

Tags: sql-server, sql-optimization

I have a table where I keep the Json data under `RelatedObject` column. Table structure are as follows;

```
+------+------------+-----------------+----------------------+
| [Id] | [ActionId] | [RelatedObject] | [InitiatedTimeStamp] |
+------+------------+-----------------+----------------------+
```

I store two different kinds of Json object. One something like this;

```
{
    "firstName": "FName",
    "lastName": "LName",
    "emailAddress": "xxx@gmail.com",    
    "contactPref": {
        "lm_contclassne": "on",
        "lm_contclassneindustrial": "on",
        "lm_contclassneconstruction": "on"
     }
}
```

Second kind is the subset of the first one. Something like this;

```
{
  "lm_contclassne": "on",
  "lm_contclassneindustrial": "on",
  "lm_contclassneconstruction": "on"
}
```

Now, the problem is selecting the Json path (in some cases properties are `lm_contclassne` and for others its `contactPref.lm_contclassne`) for the query. This is how I'm doing it.

```
SELECT [Id],
  [ActionId],
  [InitiatedTimeStamp],
  JSON_VALUE(RelatedObject, IIF(JSON_QUERY(RelatedObject, '$.contactPref') IS NULL, '$.lm_contclassne', '$.contactPref.lm_contclassne')) lm_contclassne,
  JSON_VALUE(RelatedObject, IIF(JSON_QUERY(RelatedObject, '$.contactPref') IS NULL, '$.lm_contclassneindustrial', '$.contactPref.lm_contclassneindustrial')) lm_contclassneindustrial,
  JSON_VALUE(RelatedObject, IIF(JSON_QUERY(RelatedObject, '$.contactPref') IS NULL, '$.lm_contclassneconstruction', '$.contactPref.lm_contclassneconstruction')) lm_contclassneconstruction
FROM [SaveStatus]
```

Its working fine.

My question is, is there anyway I can optimize the query? You can see I've put the same condition on each and every Json properties. Can I do the checking `IIF(JSON_QUERY(RelatedObject, '$.contactPref') IS NULL` once and use the result for rest of the select? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could shrink it down to this I suppose (it's a little more succinct):

```
SELECT [Id],
       [ActionId],
       [InitiatedTimeStamp],
       JSON_VALUE(RelatedObject, IIF(RO.cP IS NULL, '$.lm_contclassne', '$.contactPref.lm_contclassne')) lm_contclassne,
       JSON_VALUE(RelatedObject, IIF(RO.cP IS NULL, '$.lm_contclassneindustrial', '$.contactPref.lm_contclassneindustrial')) lm_contclassneindustrial,
       JSON_VALUE(RelatedObject, IIF(RO.cP IS NULL, '$.lm_contclassneconstruction', '$.contactPref.lm_contclassneconstruction')) lm_contclassneconstruction
FROM [SaveStatus] SS
     CROSS APPLY(VALUES(JSON_QUERY(RelatedObject, '$.contactPref'))) RO(cP);
```